# Refresh Power BI dataset connected to Scopus database

Tags: api, powerbi, scopus

I prepared a scientometric dashboard using Power BI which is connected directly to Scopus database by calling API keys. On my Power Bi desktop it can refresh data without any error but after publishing the dashboard to power bi website it can not be refreshed and returns a credential error:

> Last refresh failed: Wed Nov 27 2019 12:32:39 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard
>   Time) There was an error when processing the data in the dataset.Hide
>   details Message:  The credentials provided for the Web source are
>   invalid. (Source at https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus.)
>   Table: API-Scopus-All. Cluster
>   URI:  WABI-EAST-ASIA-A-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net Activity
>   ID:   7edc8fb9-5513-465d-a35b-70cc5629d0d0 Request
>   ID:   2edb255e-20fe-d1db-6b7d-2cf1b6681fc5 Time:  2019-11-27 09:02:39Z

following code is my query in Power BI. Moreover my credential on desktop is "Basic" with "User name"= my apikey

I only deleted my apikey from code. Anyone wants to reproduce results, should replace his/her Scopus apikey with APIKEY. Moreover access to Scopus database should be provided.

I appreciate any help for solving the credential issue. thanks

```
let
    Source =  1000, //the total value from a total rows api?
    Starts = List.Generate(()=>0, each _ < Source, each _ + 25),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Starts, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Json.Document(Web.Contents(
    "https://api.elsevier.com/", 
    [
        RelativePath="content/search/scopus/",
        Query=
        [
         view="complete",
                 count="25",
                 query="AFFIL ( {Environmental Research Center}  OR  {Institute for Environmental Research} )  AND  AFFIL ( {Tehran University of Medical Sciences}  OR  {Tehran University of Medical Science} ) AND  AFFIL ( {Netherlands})",
                 apiKey="APIKEY",
                 limit="40",
                 start=""&[Column1]

        ]
    ]

))),

    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"search-results"}, {"Custom.search-results"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Custom.search-results", {"opensearch:totalResults", "opensearch:startIndex", "opensearch:itemsPerPage", "opensearch:Query", "link", "entry"}, {"Custom.search-results.opensearch:totalResults", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:startIndex", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:itemsPerPage", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query", "Custom.search-results.link", "Custom.search-results.entry"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query", {"@role", "@searchTerms", "@startPage"}, {"Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query.@role", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query.@searchTerms", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query.@startPage"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.link" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query", "Custom.search-results.link"),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.link1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.link", "Custom.search-results.link", {"@_fa", "@ref", "@href", "@type"}, {"Custom.search-results.link.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.link.@ref", "Custom.search-results.link.@href", "Custom.search-results.link.@type"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.link1", "Custom.search-results.entry"),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry", "Custom.search-results.entry", {"@_fa", "link", "prism:url", "dc:identifier", "eid", "dc:title", "dc:creator", "prism:publicationName", "prism:issn", "prism:eIssn", "prism:volume", "prism:pageRange", "prism:coverDate", "prism:coverDisplayDate", "prism:doi", "pii", "dc:description", "citedby-count", "affiliation", "prism:aggregationType", "subtype", "subtypeDescription", "author-count", "author", "authkeywords", "article-number", "source-id", "fund-acr", "fund-no", "fund-sponsor", "openaccess", "openaccessFlag"}, {"Custom.search-results.entry.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.link", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:url", "Custom.search-results.entry.dc:identifier", "Custom.search-results.entry.eid", "Custom.search-results.entry.dc:title", "Custom.search-results.entry.dc:creator", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:publicationName", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:issn", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:eIssn", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:volume", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:pageRange", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:coverDate", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:coverDisplayDate", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:doi", "Custom.search-results.entry.pii", "Custom.search-results.entry.dc:description", "Custom.search-results.entry.citedby-count", "Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:aggregationType", "Custom.search-results.entry.subtype", "Custom.search-results.entry.subtypeDescription", "Custom.search-results.entry.author-count", "Custom.search-results.entry.author", "Custom.search-results.entry.authkeywords", "Custom.search-results.entry.article-number", "Custom.search-results.entry.source-id", "Custom.search-results.entry.fund-acr", "Custom.search-results.entry.fund-no", "Custom.search-results.entry.fund-sponsor", "Custom.search-results.entry.openaccess", "Custom.search-results.entry.openaccessFlag"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.link" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry1", "Custom.search-results.entry.link"),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.link1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.link", "Custom.search-results.entry.link", {"@_fa", "@ref", "@href"}, {"Custom.search-results.entry.link.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.link.@ref", "Custom.search-results.entry.link.@href"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.link1", "Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation"),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation", "Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation", {"@_fa", "affiliation-url", "afid", "affilname", "affiliation-city", "affiliation-country"}, {"Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation.affiliation-url", "Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation.afid", "Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation.affilname", "Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation.affiliation-city", "Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation.affiliation-country"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author-count" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation1", "Custom.search-results.entry.author-count", {"@limit", "@total", "$"}, {"Custom.search-results.entry.author-count.@limit", "Custom.search-results.entry.author-count.@total", "Custom.search-results.entry.author-count.$"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author-count", "Custom.search-results.entry.author"),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author", "Custom.search-results.entry.author", {"@_fa", "@seq", "author-url", "authid", "authname", "surname", "given-name", "initials", "afid"}, {"Custom.search-results.entry.author.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.@seq", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.author-url", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.authid", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.authname", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.surname", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.given-name", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.initials", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author1", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid"),
    #"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid", {"@_fa", "$"}, {"Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid.$"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid1",{"Column1", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:startIndex", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:itemsPerPage", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query.@role", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query.@searchTerms", "Custom.search-results.opensearch:Query.@startPage", "Custom.search-results.link.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.link.@type", "Custom.search-results.entry.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.link.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.link.@ref", "Custom.search-results.entry.link.@href", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:issn", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:eIssn", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:volume", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:pageRange", "Custom.search-results.entry.dc:description", "Custom.search-results.entry.affiliation.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.author-count.@limit", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.author.afid.@_fa", "Custom.search-results.entry.article-number", "Custom.search-results.entry.source-id", "Custom.search-results.link.@href"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom.search-results.entry.citedby-count", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Custom.search-results.entry.prism:doi", "DOI"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "URL", each "https://doi.org/"&[DOI]),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:coverDate", "Custom.search-results.entry.prism:coverDate - Copy"),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Custom.search-results.entry.prism:coverDate - Copy", "Date"}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns1",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"Custom.search-results.entry.prism:coverDate", "Cover date"}}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns2",{{"Cover date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type3"
```

The problem is not related to IP client:
because if I make my query in Scopus:
 (https://dev.elsevier.com/search.html#!/Scopus_Search/ScopusSearch) to produce a URL: 
(https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=AFFIL%20(%20%7BEnvironmental%20Research%20Center%7D%20%20OR%20%20%7BInstitute%20for%20Environmental%20Research%7D%20)%20%20AND%20%20AFFIL%20(%20%7BTehran%20University%20of%20Medical%20Sciences%7D%20%20OR%20%20%7BTehran%20University%20of%20Medical%20Science%7D%20)%20AND%20%20AFFIL%20(%20%7BNetherlands%7D)&apiKey="MY-API-KEY") 
and import it as web address to PBI it works well and can be refreshed without problem after publishing to PBI web. But the problem is with this simple query only one page of Scopus searched items will be returned. I need all, and because of it I changed the code as above, but it can not be refreshed after publish to PBI!

Comment: Hi Mahdi Hadi,

Sorry for the delay to respond. Based on what you need, could you show me an example link for scopus api? Perhaps the problem is not in the scopus api, it is in the conservation of Apikey when reloading the data.  In my case, Apikey kept it in a configuration file.

I am looking forward to your reply :)

Comment: Dear Francisca GV thanks for your reply, actually my problem is not resolved yet, thus no worries for your delay, I appreciate your help for anytime...I think it is better to me to share my dashboard with you, thus please let know how can I send it for you? can I email it for you?

Comment: Of course! My mail is franciscageorgue@gmail.com and I use Hangouts We can chat there :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably related to the fact that by default, the Scopus API uses the client's IP address to check if it has a subscription to Scopus. When you run the dashboard on your Power BI desktop client, requests to the Scopus API are sent from your client's IP address, and if your client IP address is set up for access to Scopus, you will get full access to Scopus data through the API as well. But when you run your dashboard on the Power BI website, requests to the Scopus API are probably sent from the Power BI server's IP address, which may not be set up for access to Scopus. Depending on your use case, you may be able to request the use of an authentication token by contacting Scopus API support.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, Please see end of my question above.